# 2 Dimentional array with Hash-map

Tags: java, hashmap, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to put a 2d array into a Hash map setup?

Example of the array would be two strings {"John", "red"},
                                         {"George", "blue}

And I would want red to correspond to john etc.

I know I can use a nested loop to go through every item in the 2d array but how would then set it up to add them to the hash-map

hashMap.put("John", "red");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every array has 2 items in the form of {Name, Color}, you can just iterate over it

```
for(String[] combo : some2DArray){
   someHashMap.Put(combo[0], combo[1]); // Or swap them, depending on what you 
                                        // want to be the key and the value
}
```

If you want to avoid the possibility of removing data because you happen to have two people with the same name there are a few approaches you can take:

- Keep the old data
- Keep the new data
- Assign the new data to a new key
- Combine the data in the same key

**Keep the old data**

Perform a check before using `HashMap#put` and see if the key already exists.
Only add the data if it doesn't exist yet.

**Keep the new data**

Use the current code, it will overwrite the old value.

**Assign the new data to a new key**

Create a new key based on your own rules and insert that.

**Combine the data in the same key**

Define your `HashMap` as `HashMap<String, List<String>>` and add the values to the list.

Comment: In retrospect: this is just a concrete implementation of what you said in your question. As far as I understood you, this is what you want. Am I correct in this?

Comment: Yea, if I did it the way I was initially going to do it I would have a problem because the loop would have gone through every single string in the array>

I wasn't sure if I could add both the {name, Color} that way without having overlapping problems.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me what you're saying, but if it's working then that's good. One thing to note though: this approach assumes that every name only occurs once. Do you know for sure that this is the case?

Comment: I have added a few approaches you can take to deal with duplicate keys.

Comment: Ill try to explain better. I have a 2d array that has  10 names and colors. I want to move the information from that array into a hashmap, but I didn't know the best way to implement that. 

The end result I want is if I say John it will tell me his color is blue. Every name only occurs once in the array.

I was going to do it using a nested for loop but I don't think that would work for adding to the hashmap because don't you have to add both the name and color at the same time, which you wouldn't be able  to do with the nested loop.

Comment: In a `HashMap` you *do* have to add both the key and the value at the same time. You can overwrite the value with a later statement but you'll always have to add it first with `put(key, value)`.

Comment: So how would I do that if I was going through the array with a nested for loop? 

Is there a better way to go around doing that?

Comment: Why do you need a nested for loop? You already know each inner array only has two fields: a name and a color. There is no need to make an inner loop, you can just use the indices directly.

Comment: Because im stupid thanks for the help just realized what needed to be done

Comment: hashmap.get is how you get something out of a hashmap right?

Comment: Yes, it is. You should read through the documentation for that kind of question though: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: So this should work right? System.out.println("The color is "+ HashMap.get(s)); s is the string that the user inputs. Im getting a "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method get(Object) from the type HashMap" error

Comment: You have to use the name of your hashmap variable instead of `HashMap.get(s)` (so f.e.: `myHashMap.get(s)`).

Comment: Is there a way I can make an if statement that would return true if the string was not in the hashmap? To Clarify I mean
if {string not there}

Answer (score -2):

How about implementing a `Pair` class, so you can use `HashMap<Pair<String,String>>` ?

EDIT: Might be that I misunderstood your question, is that what yoe were asking?